# Retrieve the correspondence for a traject

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a database that contains this informations :

```
trip1 => stop1
trip1 => stop15
trip1 => stop20

trip2 => stop8
trip2 => stop11
trip2 => stop17

trip3 => stop15
trip3 => stop11
trip3 => stop25
```

If a user want to go from stop1 to stop17 I print this information :

```
stop1 (trip1) => stop15 (trip3) => stop11 (trip2) => stop17
```

Is it possible get the correspondence stop15 and stop11 with an sql request? I'm doing it by using pl sql.

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what these stops are and how they are related. Why would you need stop15 and stop11 respectively to go to stop17? Why not stop20 and stop8? (Table structure, SQLFiddle, concrete example data and some context would help.)

Comment: You can reach only stops that are in the same trip. You can't go from stop1 to stop17 directly because they are not in same trip. So you must go to stop15 first then to stop11 then stop17. Like in subway

Comment: Okay, but why can you go from trip1->stop15 to trip3->stop11 and not from trip1->stop8 to trip2->stop20? Where are the relations? Where is the logic?

Comment: You can't go from trip to another unless if there's the same stop in both of them.

Comment: Roughly how many trips and stops are in the actual table?

Comment: A hundred but why you need this?

Comment: Was just wondering, if there were really only 3, for instance, you would know there are always going to be just a couple steps to the destination and it would be easier to solve.

Comment: this is like "the shortest path" matter between two points. right?

Comment: In my case there just one step and I don't care about the shortest path

Comment: what is the trips table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **need** the shortest path algoritm here, as @Eng. Samer T wrote.
A naive query that generates all possible pathes for this sample data gives 8 possible pathes from stop1 to stop17, while the path you pointed is the shortest one.
look at this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7742c/13

With more data this naive query may never finish, since a number of possible pathes may be endless.

```
SELECT "Path"
FROM (

select trip,
       pidstop,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT trip as root_pid,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT pidstop As root_pidstop,
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(pidstop||' ('||trip||') ', 
                         '/') As "Path"
from table1
start with pidstop = 'stop1'
connect by nocycle 
      prior pidstop = pidstop
      and prior trip <> trip
      or 
      prior trip = trip
      and prior pidstop <> pidstop
)
WHERE root_pidstop = 'stop1'
  AND pidstop = 'stop17'



/stop1 (trip1) /stop15 (trip1) /stop15 (trip3) /stop11 (trip3) /stop11 (trip2) /stop8 (trip2) /stop17 (trip2)  
/stop1 (trip1) /stop15 (trip1) /stop15 (trip3) /stop11 (trip3) /stop11 (trip2) /stop17 (trip2)  
/stop1 (trip1) /stop15 (trip1) /stop15 (trip3) /stop25 (trip3) /stop11 (trip3) /stop11 (trip2) /stop8 (trip2) /stop17 (trip2)  
/stop1 (trip1) /stop15 (trip1) /stop15 (trip3) /stop25 (trip3) /stop11 (trip3) /stop11 (trip2) /stop17 (trip2)  
/stop1 (trip1) /stop20 (trip1) /stop15 (trip1) /stop15 (trip3) /stop11 (trip3) /stop11 (trip2) /stop8 (trip2) /stop17 (trip2)  
/stop1 (trip1) /stop20 (trip1) /stop15 (trip1) /stop15 (trip3) /stop11 (trip3) /stop11 (trip2) /stop17 (trip2)  
/stop1 (trip1) /stop20 (trip1) /stop15 (trip1) /stop15 (trip3) /stop25 (trip3) /stop11 (trip3) /stop11 (trip2) /stop8 (trip2) /stop17 (trip2)  
/stop1 (trip1) /stop20 (trip1) /stop15 (trip1) /stop15 (trip3) /stop25 (trip3) /stop11 (trip3) /stop11 (trip2) /stop17 (trip2)
```